# Why this code is not efficient?

Tags: c++, performance, arm, simd, neon

I want to improve the next code, calculating the mean:

```
void calculateMeanStDev8x8Aux(cv::Mat* patch, int sx, int sy, int& mean, float& stdev)
{

    unsigned sum=0;
    unsigned sqsum=0;
    const unsigned char* aux=patch->data + sy*patch->step + sx;
    for (int j=0; j< 8; j++) {
        const unsigned char* p = (const unsigned char*)(j*patch->step + aux ); //Apuntador al inicio de la matrix           

        for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            unsigned f = *p++;
            sum += f;
            sqsum += f*f;
        }           
    }       

    mean = sum >> 6;
    int r = (sum*sum) >> 6;
    stdev = sqrtf(sqsum - r);

    if (stdev < .1) {
        stdev=0;
    }
}
```

I also improved the next loop with NEON intrinsics:

```
 for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            unsigned f = *p++;
            sum += f;
            sqsum += f*f;
        }
```

This is the code improved for the other loop:

```
        int32x4_t vsum= { 0 };
        int32x4_t vsum2= { 0 };

        int32x4_t vsumll = { 0 };
        int32x4_t vsumlh = { 0 };
        int32x4_t vsumll2 = { 0 };
        int32x4_t vsumlh2 = { 0 };

        uint8x8_t  f= vld1_u8(p); // VLD1.8 {d0}, [r0]

        //int 16 bytes /8 elementos
        int16x8_t val =  (int16x8_t)vmovl_u8(f);

        //int 32 /4 elementos *2 
        int32x4_t vall = vmovl_s16(vget_low_s16(val));
        int32x4_t valh = vmovl_s16(vget_high_s16(val));

        // update 4 partial sum of products vectors

        vsumll2 = vmlaq_s32(vsumll2, vall, vall);
        vsumlh2 = vmlaq_s32(vsumlh2, valh, valh);

        // sum 4 partial sum of product vectors
        vsum = vaddq_s32(vall, valh);
        vsum2 = vaddq_s32(vsumll2, vsumlh2);

        // do scalar horizontal sum across final vector

        sum += vgetq_lane_s32(vsum, 0);
        sum += vgetq_lane_s32(vsum, 1);
        sum += vgetq_lane_s32(vsum, 2);
        sum += vgetq_lane_s32(vsum, 3);

        sqsum += vgetq_lane_s32(vsum2, 0);
        sqsum += vgetq_lane_s32(vsum2, 1);
        sqsum += vgetq_lane_s32(vsum2, 2);
        sqsum += vgetq_lane_s32(vsum2, 3);
```

But it is more or less 30 ms more slow. Does anyone know why?

All the code is working right.

Comment: There's a lot of things that can influence performance (assuming you are measuring processing time the right way). Apparently you are using OpenCV, so I'll say that the size of the image makes a lot of difference. How big is it?

Comment: What does the unit "mms" mean? Is it "millimilliseconds"? "millimeterseconds"?

Comment: Why is this tagged C? It is C++. `cv::Mat` etc.

Comment: Are you using this with real-time streaming data?

Comment: The image is 320X240, yes I´m using this in realtime, so the time is different for frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to Lundin.  Yes, instruction sets like ARM where you have a register based index or some reach with an immediate index you might benefit encouraging the compiler to use indexing.  Also though the ARM for example can increment its pointer register in the load instruction, basically *p++ in one instruction.

it is always a toss up using p[i] or p[i++]  vs *p or *p++, some instruction sets are much more obvious which path to take.

Likewise your index. if you are not using it counting down instead of up can save an instruction per loop, maybe more.  Some might do this:

```
inc reg
cmp reg,#7
bne loop_top
```

If you were counting down though you might save an instruction per loop:

```
dec reg
bne loop_top
```

or even one processor I know of

```
decrement_and_jump_if_not_zero  loop_top
```

The compilers usually know this and you dont have to encourage them.  BUT if you use the p[i] form where the memory read order is important, then the compiler cant or at least should not arbitrarily change the order of the reads.  So for that case you would want to have the code count down.

So I tried all of these things:

```
unsigned fun1 ( const unsigned char *p, unsigned *x )
{
    unsigned sum;
    unsigned sqsum;
    int i;
    unsigned f;


    sum = 0;
    sqsum = 0;
    for(i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        f = *p++;
        sum += f;
        sqsum += f*f;
    }
    //to keep the compiler from optimizing
    //stuff out
    x[0]=sum;
    return(sqsum);
}

unsigned fun2 ( const unsigned char *p, unsigned *x  )
{
    unsigned sum;
    unsigned sqsum;
    int i;
    unsigned f;


    sum = 0;
    sqsum = 0;
    for(i=8;i--;)
    {
        f = *p++;
        sum += f;
        sqsum += f*f;
    }
    //to keep the compiler from optimizing
    //stuff out
    x[0]=sum;
    return(sqsum);
}

unsigned fun3 ( const unsigned char *p, unsigned *x )
{
    unsigned sum;
    unsigned sqsum;
    int i;

    sum = 0;
    sqsum = 0;
    for(i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        sum += (unsigned)p[i];
        sqsum += ((unsigned)p[i])*((unsigned)p[i]);
    }
    //to keep the compiler from optimizing
    //stuff out
    x[0]=sum;
    return(sqsum);
}

unsigned fun4 ( const unsigned char *p, unsigned *x )
{
    unsigned sum;
    unsigned sqsum;
    int i;

    sum = 0;
    sqsum = 0;
    for(i=8; i;i--)
    {
        sum += (unsigned)p[i-1];
        sqsum += ((unsigned)p[i-1])*((unsigned)p[i-1]);
    }
    //to keep the compiler from optimizing
    //stuff out
    x[0]=sum;
    return(sqsum);
}
```

with both gcc and llvm (clang).  And of course both unrolled the loop since it was a constant.  gcc, for each of the experiments produce the same code, in cases a subtle register mix change.  And I would argue a bug as at least one of them the reads were not in the order described by the code.

gcc solutions for all four were this, with some read reordering, notice the reads being out of order from the source code.  If this were against hardware/logic that relied on the reads being in the order described by the code, you would have a big problem.

```
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e92d05f0    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, sl}
   4:   e5d06001    ldrb    r6, [r0, #1]
   8:   e00a0696    mul sl, r6, r6
   c:   e4d07001    ldrb    r7, [r0], #1
  10:   e02aa797    mla sl, r7, r7, sl
  14:   e5d05001    ldrb    r5, [r0, #1]
  18:   e02aa595    mla sl, r5, r5, sl
  1c:   e5d04002    ldrb    r4, [r0, #2]
  20:   e02aa494    mla sl, r4, r4, sl
  24:   e5d0c003    ldrb    ip, [r0, #3]
  28:   e02aac9c    mla sl, ip, ip, sl
  2c:   e5d02004    ldrb    r2, [r0, #4]
  30:   e02aa292    mla sl, r2, r2, sl
  34:   e5d03005    ldrb    r3, [r0, #5]
  38:   e02aa393    mla sl, r3, r3, sl
  3c:   e0876006    add r6, r7, r6
  40:   e0865005    add r5, r6, r5
  44:   e0854004    add r4, r5, r4
  48:   e5d00006    ldrb    r0, [r0, #6]
  4c:   e084c00c    add ip, r4, ip
  50:   e08c2002    add r2, ip, r2
  54:   e082c003    add ip, r2, r3
  58:   e023a090    mla r3, r0, r0, sl
  5c:   e080200c    add r2, r0, ip
  60:   e5812000    str r2, [r1]
  64:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  68:   e8bd05f0    pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, sl}
  6c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

the index for the loads and subtle register mixing was the only difference between functions from gcc, all of the operations were the same in the same order.

llvm/clang:

```
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e92d41f0    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, lr}
   4:   e5d0e000    ldrb    lr, [r0]
   8:   e5d0c001    ldrb    ip, [r0, #1]
   c:   e5d03002    ldrb    r3, [r0, #2]
  10:   e5d08003    ldrb    r8, [r0, #3]
  14:   e5d04004    ldrb    r4, [r0, #4]
  18:   e5d05005    ldrb    r5, [r0, #5]
  1c:   e5d06006    ldrb    r6, [r0, #6]
  20:   e5d07007    ldrb    r7, [r0, #7]
  24:   e08c200e    add r2, ip, lr
  28:   e0832002    add r2, r3, r2
  2c:   e0882002    add r2, r8, r2
  30:   e0842002    add r2, r4, r2
  34:   e0852002    add r2, r5, r2
  38:   e0862002    add r2, r6, r2
  3c:   e0870002    add r0, r7, r2
  40:   e5810000    str r0, [r1]
  44:   e0010e9e    mul r1, lr, lr
  48:   e0201c9c    mla r0, ip, ip, r1
  4c:   e0210393    mla r1, r3, r3, r0
  50:   e0201898    mla r0, r8, r8, r1
  54:   e0210494    mla r1, r4, r4, r0
  58:   e0201595    mla r0, r5, r5, r1
  5c:   e0210696    mla r1, r6, r6, r0
  60:   e0201797    mla r0, r7, r7, r1
  64:   e8bd41f0    pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, lr}
  68:   e1a0f00e    mov pc, lr
```

much easier to read and follow, perhaps thinking about a cache and getting the reads all in one shot.  llvm in at least one case got the reads out of order as well.

```
00000144 <fun4>:
 144:   e92d40f0    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
 148:   e5d0c007    ldrb    ip, [r0, #7]
 14c:   e5d03006    ldrb    r3, [r0, #6]
 150:   e5d02005    ldrb    r2, [r0, #5]
 154:   e5d05004    ldrb    r5, [r0, #4]
 158:   e5d0e000    ldrb    lr, [r0]
 15c:   e5d04001    ldrb    r4, [r0, #1]
 160:   e5d06002    ldrb    r6, [r0, #2]
 164:   e5d00003    ldrb    r0, [r0, #3]
```

Yes, for averaging some values from ram, order is not an issue, moving on.

So the compiler choose the unrolled path and didnt care about the micro-optmizations.  because of the size of the loop both choose to burn a bunch of registers holding one of the loaded values per loop then either performing the adds from those temporary reads or the multiplies.  if we increase the size of the loop a little I would expect to see sum and sqsum accumulations within the unrolled loop as it runs out of registers, or the threshold will be reached where they choose not to unroll the loop.

If I pass the length in, and replace the 8's in the code above with that passed in length, forcing the compiler to make a loop out of this.  You sorta see the optimizations, instructions like this are used:

```
  a4:   e4d35001    ldrb    r5, [r3], #1
```

And being arm they do a modification of the loop register in one place and branch if not equal a number of instructions later...because they can.

Granted this is a math function, but using float is painful.  And using multplies is painful, divides are much worse, fortunately a shift was used.  and fortunately this was unsigned so that you could use the shift (the compiler would/should have known to use an arithmetic shift if available if you used a divide against a signed number).

So basically focus on micro-optmizations of the inner loop since it gets run multiple times, and if this can be changed so it becomes shifts and adds, if possible, or arranging the data so you can take it out of the loop (if possible, dont waste other copy loops elsewhere to do this)

```
const unsigned char* p = (const unsigned char*)(j*patch->step + aux );
```

you could get some speed. I didnt try it but because it is a loop in a loop the compiler probably wont unroll that loop...

Long story short, you might get some gains depending on the instruction set against a dumber compiler, but this code is not really bad so the compiler can optimize it as well as you can.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you will probably get very good, detailed answers on stuff like this if you post at [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) instead.

Some comments regarding efficiency and suspicious variable types:

`unsigned f = *p++;` You will probably be better off if you access `p` through array indexing and then use p[i] to access the data. This is highly dependent on compiler, cache memory optimizations etc (some ARM guru can give a better advise than me in this matter).

Btw the whole const char to int looks highly suspicious. I take it those chars are to be regarded as 8-bit unsigned integers? Standard C `uint8_t` is likely a better type to for this, `char` has various undefined signedness issues that you want to avoid.

Also, why are you doing wild mixing of `unsigned` and `int`? You are asking for implicit integer balancing bugs.

`stdev < .1`. Just a minor thing: change this to `.1f` or you enforce an implicit promotion of your float to double, since .1 is a double literal.

Answer (score 1):

As your data is being read in in groups of 8 bytes, depending on your hardware bus and the alignment of the array itself, you can probably get some gains by reading the inner loop in via a single long long read, then either manually splitting the numbers into seperate values, or using ARM intrinsics to do the adds in parallel with some inline asm using the add8 instruction (adds 4 numbers together at a time in 1 register) or do a touch of shifting and use add16 to allow the values to overflow into 16-bits worth of space.  There is also a dual signed multiply and accumulate instruction which makes your first accumulation loop nearly perfectly supported via ARM with just a little help.  Also, if the data coming in could be massaged to be 16-bit values, that could also speed this up.

As to why the NEON is slower, my guess is the overhead in setting up the vectors along with the added data you are pushing around with larger types is killing any performance it might gain with such a small set of data.  The original code is very ARM friendly to begin with, which means the setup overhead is probably killing you.  When in doubt, look at the assembly output.  That will tell you what's truly going on.  Perhaps the compiler is pushing and popping data all over the place when trying to use the intrinsics - wouldn't be the first time I've see this sort of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lundin, dwelch and Michel.
I made the next improvement and it seems the best for my code.
I´m trying to  decrease the number of cycles improving the cache access, because is only accessing to cache one time.

```
int step=patch->step;
 for (int j=0; j< 8; j++) {
        p = (uint8_t*)(j*step + aux ); /

        i=8;
        do {                
            f=p[i];
            sum += f;
            sqsum += f*f;

        } while(--i);

}
```